# Crystal Reports combine sum total with percentage calculation as string

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table of data in Crystal, using the summarise feature I can add a sum total at the bottom of each column but I'd like to add the percentage calculation in brackets next to the sum total.

For example I have,

```
Column A 432

Column B 191
```

Is there a formula I can use to show "SumColumn B (SumColumnB/SumColumnA %)"?

Comment: where you want to do the sum total in design?

Comment: In the grouping footer, managed to resolve this issue, will post the solution below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this with the code below:

```
totext(sum({table1.ColumnB},{table.Site}),0)&" ("&totext(sum({table1.ColumnB},{table1.Site})/sum({table1.ColumnA},{table1.Site})*100,2)&"%)"
```

Using the table.Site to sum each group separately.

Resulting in following output:

```
191 (44.21%)
```